# Substring Select MySQL

Tags: mysql

My problem is the following:

I got this:

```
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'cr' limit 1;
```

```
+------------+
| table_name |
+------------+
| users      |
+------------+
```

and I want to extract the first letter only:

I am trying:

```
substring(SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'cr' limit 1,1,1);
```

Comment: What are you getting? My guess: A syntax error, but it helps to see the *exact* error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't supposed to use `SUBSTRING()` on a query, but you can use it on a column, like this:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(table_name, 1, 1) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'cr' limit 1;
```

You can also use `LEFT(table_name, 1)` which is a lot more self-explanatory.

Comment: Indexes for `SUBSTRING` in MySQL start at 1, not 0.

Comment: @MichaelMior Was about to correct that but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

`SUBSTRING` should be applied to the `table_name` column:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(table_name, 1, 1) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'cr' LIMIT 1;
```